# Intuitive explanations for Gaussian distribution function and mahalanobis distance

Tags: probability

I was wondering If anyone could give intuitive explanations for the multivariate Gaussian distribution function and mahalanobis distance? My professor didn't explain these in probability class, they were only defined...

Where did the formula come from? Why is the Gaussian function the way it is? Is there a way to intuitively explain mahalanobis distance?

Thank you for any support!!

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61480/motivation-of-the-gaussian-integral/61507#61507) is some intuition for the single-variable Gaussian distribution function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the Mahalanobis distance, have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424445/bottom-to-top-explanation-of-the-mahanalobis-distance/424459#424459) and [here](http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/02/15/what-is-mahalanobis-distance/)

Comment: +1 Thnx @Avitus you're a life saver :) I will get back to you on the logistic regression when I can. Sorry a bit busy at the moment with many new things to learn :)