# Derivation of Mahalanobis Distance

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I was recently reading up on the [Mahalanobis Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahalanobis_distance), and understood how it generalizes distance measures for multivariate data such as the Euclidean Distance. However, what got me wondering was how does one derive the formula constructively? I understand how this general form applies in particular cases, but is there a way to construct this general formula from 'first principles'?

Particularly, could someone explain what is the significance of the inverted covariance matrix? (especially in the non-trivial case when it is not a diagonal matrix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than "derive", I would talk about "why". For some explanations have a look at my answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424445/bottom-to-top-explanation-of-the-mahanalobis-distance/424459#424459) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428064/distance-of-a-test-point-from-the-center-of-an-ellipsoid/428160#428160). For a direct application consider for example the $p$-multivariate normal distribution

$$f(x|\theta, \Sigma)=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^\frac{p}{2}|\Sigma|^\frac{p}{2}} 
\exp\left( -\frac{1}{2}\langle (x-\theta),\Sigma^{-1}(x-\theta)\rangle   \right);$$

the exponent is (up to a factor $-\frac{1}{2}$) the square Mahalanobis distance of $x$ from the mean $\theta$. This is an example of kernel (gaussian); it is widely used in density estimation. In the bivariate case, the level curves / density contours

$$\langle (x-\theta),\Sigma^{-1}(x-\theta)\rangle = K $$

are ellipses, with the usual statistical / mathematical interpretation.

In more mathematical terms, the squared Mahalanobis distance is an example of Bregman divergence generated by the convex function $F(x)=\frac{1}{2}\langle x,\Sigma^{-1}x\rangle$. In the regression context, it is also related to leverage; I refer to specialized texts for more details.

- References

On Bregman divergences and Mahalanobis distance (with applications in topology): http://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.2196v1.pdf

On the geoemtry induced by the divergence with generator given by $F(x)=\frac{1}{2}\langle x,\Sigma^{-1}x\rangle$ (pag. 8-9 in particular):
http://bulletin.pan.pl/(58-1)183.pdf

This second reference shows that the Mahalanobis distance induces a Riemannian geometry
structure on a certain manifold with curvature tensor induced by the positive definite matrix $\Sigma^{-1}$. This is nice.

Comment: @JP_smasher: did it help?

Comment: Hi it did help, but I'm more curious about a constructive derivation. Could you share some 'specialized texts'?

Comment: please, feel free to accept and upvote the answer if you found it useful. I add some references at the bottom of it